# safari not displaying header background images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

In my website the top header background and the "Kreation Team" Div background are not displaying in safari on ipads and iphones but it is visible on imacs and macbooks. I mean in small devices the background images are not visible.

If you go in Chrome and safari separately you can see the difference...
Please help how to solve this?`

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="row pull-right hidden-xs" style="padding:20px 20px 0 0;">
                <ul style="font-size: 15px;">
                    <li><a href="http://kreationhandlooms.com" alt="Kreation House of Cotton home page">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://kreationhandlooms.com/aboutus" alt="Kreation House of Cotton about us page">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://kreationhandlooms.com/branches" alt="Kreation House of Cotton contact us page">Branches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://kreationhandlooms.com/gallery" alt="Kreation House of Cotton gallery page">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                    <h1>KREATION <br>House of Cotton</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 30px;">Srilankan Quality Handloom Manufacturer</h2>
                    <button class="jumbo-btn hidden-xs" onclick="
                    location.href='http://kreationhandlooms.com/aboutus';" alt="Kreation House of Cotton about us page">About Us</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron{
background-image: url("images/silk saree.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center 10%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 720px;
width: 100%;
font-family: nexabold;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 510px) and (max-width: 2000px){
.jumbotron .container-fluid .row-fluid{
padding:160px 0 0 10px;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 510px){
.jumbotron .container-fluid .row-fluid{
padding-top: 80px;
}
}

.jumbo-btn{
padding:10px 20px;
border: 3px solid white;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 18px;
background:transparent;
transition: all 0.4s;
}

 .jumbotron h1{
 font-weight: bold;
 }

.jumbo-btn:hover{
 background-color: grey;
 color: white;

border:3px solid white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 760px){
.jumbotron .row-fluid h1{
 margin:0 0 30px 0;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

there was an error in console too

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Include proper version of jQuery before bootstrap.

Comment: @Riya  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You need to have jQuery version lower thn 3. You are using 3.1.1 right now.

Comment: i changed it and now it works..I want to know why header background is not displaying in Safari mobile and Tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Your console error is due to the fact that you are not loading **jQuery** in your HTML. You need to add something along the lines of:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This may also be what's causing problems with your images. If you're still experiencing issues, it helps to have a working example. Try creating a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code, and append the link to your original post.

**Edit:** I just took a look at your code, and the image isn't loading on Safari mobile because of `background-attachment: fixed` on line `214` of `stylesheet.css` for the CSS class `.jumbotron`. If you remove that from your code, the image works fine. If you need to keep the CSS for the desktop, just use a simple media query to target mobile devices.

Comment: i included the javascript in the end of the html file.Sorry for not including in the question. :)

Comment: In your code above, you are loading **jQuery 3.1.1**. The console error is telling you that you need to load **jQuery 1.9.1** or higher, but lower than version **3**. Obviously version **3.1.1** is not lower than version **3**, so try loading another version. You can use my code above, or visit [this link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) to view Google's Hosted Libraries for **jQuery**, just choose one between **1.9.1** and **2.2.4**.

Comment: changing to 2.2.4 worked for me... so what's making the images not displaying in mobile safari browsers? @Matthew

Comment: i need background attachment to be fixed because that makes the background fixed when scrolling effect. That effect won't work if i remove attachment:fixed. Can you advice me the media query for safari small screens?

Comment: The iPhone 6s Plus (the largest iPhone screen) is 414px wide, so you could use the following code to remove `background-attachment`, try `@media (max-width: 415px) {.jumbotron {background-attachment: initial;}}`